# Rajawali SurfaceView with OnClickListener NPE on android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.onResume()

Tags: android, android-fragments, opengl-es, onclicklistener, rajawali

I'm having a serious problem with [Rajawali library](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) using GLSurfaceView ! I'm including a Rajawali SurfaceView into an XML Fragment but the inflate in the 'onCreateView' fails.

Actually, it works when I call the fragment in the mainActivity like this :

```
Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

However, it's not working when I call this in an OnClickListener or in the Drawer like this :

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myFragment c = new myFragment ();
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(c);
            }
        });
```

The trace give me this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.onResume()' on a null object reference
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:562)
at org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView.onResume(RajawaliSurfaceView.java:89)
at org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow(RajawaliSurfaceView.java:106)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you set the renderer of the surfaceview correctly in onCreateView of the fragment? I always got your error message whenever I missed a proper call of surfaceView.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);

Comment: Yep, I figured this out. It works fine now :)